# My app icon is not coming up in the simulator, can someone help me?

Tags: icons, ios-simulator

Can anyone help me? I added the images into my project folder and I dragged the images onto the app icon places in the summary. What am i doing wrong? Someone please help me

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes in xCode, simply clean your program by pressing Command + Shift + K or going to the Product tab in your Finder bar and pressing clean.

Hope this helps!